In Ghidra is there a way to add an overall top comment rather than just the top of one memory block?
I'm writing some Loaders for Ghidra for a file format based on Zip that includes an XML file and one or more memory blocks.
I'd like to add the important parts of the XML as comments at the very start of the listing. Normally I add comments inside the load() function like this:
program.getListing().setComment(loadAddress, CodeUnit.PRE_COMMENT, "my comment");

But this will add the comment to the start of the memory block where the address is. Since there can be multiple blocks that start at the same address, think overlays or paged memory, etc, you can't really guarantee which block will be first, or I don't know how.
Is there some way to add a comment that will always be at the top of the listing no matter the memory bloc structure of the program?
